# How to: fit_generator in keras

Tags: python, keras

I am a little bit confused how to use `fit_generator` in `keras`.

By example lets say:

- we have 10000 datapoints
- we want to run for 10 epochs
- with batch size of 512

Using `fit` we just:

```
x, y = load_data()
model.fit(x=x, y=y, batch_size=512, epochs=10)
```

where `load_data` loads all the data.

Now how to do the same with `fit_generator`.

Its not clear to me how it is processed when using `fit_generator`. If I have the following generator:

```
def data_generator():
    for x, y in load_data_per_line():
        yield x, y
```

In the generator above each time it `yields` one data point. And:

```
def data_generator_2():
    x_output = []
    y_output = []
    i = 0
    for x, y in load_data_per_line():
        x_output[i] = x
        y_output[i] = y
        i = i + 1
        if i == batch_size:
           yield x_output, y_output
           i = 0
           x_output = []
           y_output = []
```

In the above generator every time it `yields` batch size data points(512 in this case).

To achieve the same as `fit` but using `fit_generator`:

```
model.fit_generator(data_generator(), steps_per_epoch=10000 / 512, epochs=10)
```

or

```
model.fit_generator(data_generator_2(), steps_per_epoch=10000 / 512, epochs=10)
```

Or both are wrong(`fit_generator` and `data_generator`s)? If any of them is correct, does is guaranties that all data points will be processed and also be processed sequentially?

Any insight is useful

Answer (score 2):

Generator 2 is almost ok, but it should better return numpy arrays:

```
yield np.asarray(x_output),np.asarray(y_output)
```

Also, it should be infinite:

```
while True: 

    #the code inside to loop infinitely
```

The first one will not return batches and will fail.

You will probably have a problem in `steps_per_epoch`, because 10000 is not a multiple of 512. You need integer steps. You may inside the generator check `if i == 10000:` and pass a smaller batch as the last batch.

Then you've got `(10000 //512) + (10000 % 512)` steps or batches.

All batches will be read in sequence, but keras automatically shuffles the content of these batches, use `suffle=False`. If you use multithreading (not the case), then you need to create thread safe generators or use a keras `Sequence`.

Comment: Just a curiosity, so in this case, the last batch won't have size of 512 and that is fine right?

Comment: That is fine, as long as you don't let your generator try to read more than allowed.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. as the purpose of fit generator is to train a model with a lot of data why it assumes that I have to know the number of data points?? what happens if for any reason i do not know the exact number of data points? how to set the steps in that case?

Comment: If you want to put exactly the entire data in one epoch, you must find a way to calculate the steps (even if the generator itself does that calculation for you). But you're not required to do that. You can use any number of steps, the only thing that will happen is that you will not be in sync with the size of the data.

Comment: The generators must be "endless", and the "steps" is just a way to tell when to stop.